# Grouping of rows in R

Tags: r, grouping, rows

I am new to R and have a requirement as below.
I have a data frame as below,

```
    Date  Name
1 11/17/2014 A
2 11/17/2014 B
3 11/17/2014 C
4 11/18/2014 D
5 11/18/2014 A
6 11/18/2014 B
7 11/19/2014 E
8 11/19/2014 F
9 11/19/2014 G
```

Now, I want the output as below

```
11/17/2014  11/18/2014 11/19/2014
A             D           E
B             A           F 
C             B           G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with split and cbind:

```
ll = lapply(split(ddf,ddf$Date), function(x) x[2])
dd = do.call(cbind, ll)
names(dd) = names(ll)
dd
  11/17/2014 11/18/2014 11/19/2014
1          A          D          E
2          B          A          F
3          C          B          G
```

Comment: `data.frame(split(dat$Name, dat$Date),check.names=FALSE)`